# How do I call an existing python file with multiple functions from a main.py Bottle

Tags: python, routes, bottle

Currently, my code is like this where I upload 2 files but I need to process them in temp files via another existing parse.py file with multiple functions.

How can I call them in Templates.py?

I tried adding import parse.py but it would give an error.

### templates.py

```
@route('/')
def index():
return template('index')

@route('/', method='POST')
def upload():
incfile = request.files.get('uploadinc')
datfile = request.files.get('uploadhex')

macro, ext1 = os.path.splitext(incfile.filename)
data, ext2 = os.path.splitext(datfile.filename)
if ext1 not in ('.txt'):
    return 'File extension not allowed.'
if ext2 not in ('.txt'):
    return 'File extension not allowed.'
incfile.filename = 'macro.txt'
datfile.filename = 'data.txt'

curr_dir = os.getcwd()
print(curr_dir)
temp_dir = os.path.join(curr_dir, r'temp01')
if os.path.exists(temp_dir):
   shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
os.makedirs(temp_dir)

incfile.save(temp_dir)  
datfile.save(temp_dir)   
clean_up(temp_dir)  // gives error

@route('/')
def clean_up():      // gives error
```

### parse.py

```
 import os, sys, re, binascii

 def clean_up():

    if os.path.exists("dataparse.txt"):
            os.remove("dataparse.txt")
    else:
            print("Creating new files...")

    if os.path.exists("out3.txt"):
            os.remove("out3.txt")
    else:
            print("Creating new files...")

def parse_hexdump():
    a = open("data.txt","r")
    b = open("dataparse.txt","a")
    w = open("out3.txt","a")
   str = a.readline()
   w.write(str)
   for line in a:
   if line.startswith('MD') or line.startswith('END OF DISPLAY'):
     continue
   else:
     strline = line[5:40:]  # Slice lines from 5-40 to another file
     b.write(strline+'\n')
  b.close()
  w.close()
```

Comment: *"I tried adding import parse.py but it would give an error.*" - what was the error?  Are you saying you have two scripts called `parse.py`?

Comment: What does the directory structure look like between these two files? Are they in the same directory?

Comment: The directory structure is  BottleTempl --> templates.py, parse.py       BottleTempl --> views --> index.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `import parse`, you don't put `.py` at the end of an import statement. Since you seem to want to just use the functions rather than calling `parse.clean_up`, you could instead do `from parse import clean_up`. The file `parse` needs to either be in your local directory (where you're running the python interpreter) or in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: That is poor advice. Use `from parse import clean_up`, not `from parse import *`.

Comment: Thanks scnerd and ron.